# I have an image as background inside a div.I want to make picture fit in responsive

Tags: html, css

I tried using photoshop and I need to know how much height should be given for image in photoshop for each widths 575.98px ,767.98px,991.98px,1199.98px to get a good image.

@media (max-width: 575.98px) { ... }

@media (max-width: 767.98px) { ... }

@media (max-width: 991.98px) { ... }

@media (max-width: 1199.98px) { ... }

Comment: set your div height and width 100%

Comment: As of my knowledge that depends on the height of the image because no two images are same or if the image is in partial section that will make a huge mess in responsive. If need help with the responsive image in partial section comment back I have written a bit of jquery to fix it.

Comment: A fiddle or an image might give us an idea to help what you actually trying to achieve.

Answer (score 0):

Whatever the image **class**, **id** or just the tag is, apply a `width` of `100%;`

```
img {

   width: 100%; 

}
```